# How can I remove the grid lines in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

[image]

I'm using charts in my react app. I tried using the Scales and `gridlines: false` option but it is not working from me.
the image shows my code.

Thank you.

Comment: In the future, using code as text is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check a [chart.js sample](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/advanced/line-gradient.html). From there I found some deviations in the object setup of your example

```
        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    // Here starts your snippet
                }]
            },
            options: {
                // The options are outside of the datasets property
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        gridLines: {
                          display: false
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        gridLines: {
                          display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Edit 1: updated the scales with the gridLines property

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to remove gridlines and if you want to enable X and Y axis its useful

```
 gridLines: {
                  display: true,
                  zeroLineColor:'white',
                  color:'transparent'
                }
```